# Extra space being deleted after selecting a word?

Tags: macos, text-input

Frequently I double-click to select a word, then press "delete". Recently it seems the behaviour somehow changed to also delete the space before the word. Is there a way to revert this?

For example (cursor is `|`, selection is `#`):

> this is some text|

I double-click on "text":

> this is some #text#|

Press delete:

> this is some|

What I expected:

> this is some |

Answer (score 4):

This is by design. If you don’t want the space trimmed, use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to delete the word.

> this is some text|

goes to

> this is some |

Comment: Is there a way to set this as default behavior?

Comment: I'm asking if there's a way to make it not delete spaces without having to press alt.

Comment: not that I know of. I didnt even know that space is deleted in selection.